# Program does not work (Interest program with own math method) (Unhandelled exception type error) (Homework)

Tags: java

The following program is meant to calcuate simple interest given the formula i = p*r*t, given the user input and putting that into its own method (Must) , however, when running it i get the error "Unhandelled exception type IOException..." I tried implementing a try catch block previously but it resulted into more errors

```
import java.io.*;

public class cInterest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    }

    public static double balance(double principal, double rate, double years) {

        double amount = 0;

        String input;
        BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));

        System.out.print("How much would you like to take out? ");
        input = myInput.readLine();
        principal = Double.parseDouble(input);

        System.out.print("Enter the interest rate: ");
        input = myInput.readLine();
        rate = Double.parseDouble(input);

        for (int i = 1; i < years; i++) {
            amount = principal * rate * years;
            amount += principal;
        }
        return amount; // - principal;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your `balance()` method doesn't declare that it might throw an IOException.

Comment: You don't call the `balance` method from `main` is this a typo?

Comment: use try catch and fix the other problems

Comment: how would i call it from the main

Answer (score 0):

> however, when running it i get the error "Unhandelled exception type IOException..."

You do not get the exception when the program is run (actually, your `main()` method is still empty, so nothing would be executed), but the **compiler** gives this error when compiling your code.

You either need to catch the exception or have your method let it pass on, like

```
public static double balance(double principal, double rate, double years) throws IOException { ... }
```

The background is that your `myInput.readLine();` **could** throw an `IOException` - this either needs to be passed on to the calling method as shown above, or it needs to be handled by a `try{}-catch()-block`:

```
try {
    input = myInput.readLine();
} catch(IOException ioex) {
    ioex.printStackTrace();
    // ... additional code to handle the exception properly
}
```

You should also avoid having `main()` throw exceptions - if you choose the first approach from above and let balance throw the `IOException`, handle it in the main method latest. The following code snippet also shows how to call the `balance` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        balance(1, 2, 3);
    } catch(IOException ioex) {
        ioex.printStackTrace();
        // ... additional code to handle the exception properly
    }
}
```

See also [Lesson: Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Comment: I tried and passed it into the calling method shown above, the program runs however, does not output the commanding intro questions.

Comment: The code from the question does not show that you are calling `balance` from the `main` method at all - did you fix that?

Comment: How would I call it from the main?

Comment: See my updated answer - I have not checked if the parameters (1,2,3) make sense, but that is how you can call it

Answer (score 0):

```
myInput.readLine(); can throw `IOException` so you **must** handle it somewhere.
```

Use:

```
try {
    myInput.readLine();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And try to solve other problems.
Also remove `throws` declaration from `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to simply declare that your method throws `IOException` (and you'll need to do this to the `main` method too, if you call `balance` from there):

```
public static double balance(double principal, double rate, double years) throws IOException {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
```

You may want to try using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead of `InputStreamReader` - its a bit easier to use for this sort of thing

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

In order for your code to be executed you'll need to call it from the `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    balance(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: this simply runs the program but the intro questions to the user do not come up

Comment: @user2133068 are you calling the double method from the main method?